# Excessive failed logon attempts, cannot trace b/c of missing info

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have a Windows 2008R2 server that is reporting a constant stream of failed logon attempts.
Someone is brute-forcing this server and I cannot tell from where. The EvenIDs triggered are 4625
Below is an example of the Audit Entry

```
An account failed to log on.

Subject:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       -
    Account Domain:     -
    Logon ID:       0x0

Logon Type:         3

Account For Which Logon Failed:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       SEMINAR
    Account Domain:     

Failure Information:
    Failure Reason:     Unknown user name or bad password.
    Status:         0xc000006d
    Sub Status:     0xc0000064

Process Information:
    Caller Process ID:  0x0
    Caller Process Name:    -

Network Information:
    Workstation Name:   
    Source Network Address: -
    Source Port:        -

Detailed Authentication Information:
    Logon Process:      NtLmSsp 
    Authentication Package: NTLM
    Transited Services: -
    Package Name (NTLM only):   -
    Key Length:     0
```

The NTLM Operational Logs:

```
NTLM server blocked audit: Audit Incoming NTLM Traffic that would be blocked
Calling process PID: 756
Calling process name: C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe
Calling process LUID: 0x3e4
Calling process user identity: EW2$
Calling process domain identity: ABC
Mechanism OID: (NULL)
```

The user is not a real user
Network information is completely missing.
I have logged all NTLM messages in event log and didn't get any additional information.
I am not savvy enough with network monitors to find this NTLM attempt.

I tried closing the public and private firewall profiles, the attempts still happen.

What else can I do to trace the origin of these sign in attempts?

Comment: Logon Type 3 is a network logon, so this is someone trying to access a website (IIS), a shared folder or printer, or any of the hidden administrative shares or IPC share. Is this server running IIS? If so, make sure logging is enabled and then look in the IIS logs.